# Is it normal that in Apple Photos inside "Imports" tab Photos are not in chronological order?

Tags: macos, photos.app

Is it normal that in Apple Photos inside "Imports" tab Photos are not in chronological order?
In "Library" photos are in chronological order, but in "Imports" not, is it normal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is normal, as they are in the that order you imported them.

Comment: And - to clarify - I mean inside one series of imported 1000 photos, they are not sorted chronologically. I hope it's understandable what I mean... :D

Comment: Because usually they were in chronological order

Comment: > I mean inside one series of imported 1000 photos, they are not sorted chronologically.

They must have just not been imported chronologically then, even for groups of imports they are sorted by when they are imported.

Comment: Ok, so nothing to worry 
Thank you